# Error con libreria javascript 3.3.1

Tags: html, jquery

desde hace algún tiempo, no se exactamente cuanto, me aparecen un par de errores en consola que creo que tienen que ver con la libreria de jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He dejado la pagina practicamente vacia solo con este enlace y en console me siguen saliendo errores. Pongo un ejemplo de la pagina.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Page</title>
   
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En principio todo funciona correctamente pero no entiendo por que esos errores. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿No será que alguna extensión en el navegador es la que esta dando error? Intenta abrir la página en modo incognito, normalmente las extensiones no se cargan

Comment: te suena algo llamado mixplanel?

Comment: Aparentemente proporcionó el html incorrecto (lo corregí en la edición).
La versión actual de `Jquery 3.7.0`  y no `3.3.1`.
Siempre se recomienda ir a la [pagina](https://jquery.com/download/)  oficial que tiene el link, las versiones antiguas ademas de tener bugs tienen una serie de problemas de seguridad

Answer (score -1):

Muchas gracias a todos. Como ha dicho el compañero Marcos, era  por una extensión. Gracias Marcos. Lo he resuelto desactivando uno a uno las extensiones mas "Raras" que tenia en google hasta dar con la que era.
En este caso no es digno de renombrar.

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una respuesta diciendo "gracias". En su lugar, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que consideres como la mejor solución a tu problema. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/387014)

Comment: Como lo hago? Ellos han comentado  no han contestado.

Comment: Hola @LorenzoMartín, me alegro que hayas encontrado la solución! Te diría que dado a que realmente el problema no era jQuery, deberías considerar eliminar la respuesta y la pregunta. A menos que quieras [edit] tu respuesta y detallar que que extensión causaba el problema y como lo solucionaste.

Comment: Bueno, en este caso no hay ninguna respuesta, pero el punto es que no uses el área de las respuestas para decir gracias ya que esto no es un foro. Cómo no hay otra respuesta, sugiero que cuentes como resolviste el problema.

Comment: Resolví el problema tal y como me comento el compañero Marcos. No crees que nos la agarramos con papel de fumar?